# Modify Default.aspx start page, insert three webpartzones instead one

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part-zone

My Default.aspx in edit mode looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to insert another two webpartzones in "Top" zone?
[image]

Ideally I'd want to make this design(becouse I have webparts with such width):
[image]

Is it possible and give please any links how can I do it? I watched out-of-box webpartpages, but there is no suitable one. Also I don't think I can set any another page to be a start page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your webpart zones in the following table.

```
<table width="100%">
    <!-- top row -->
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <!-- top left zone -->
        </td>
            <!-- top middle zone. This is the existing zone in your page. -->
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- top right zone -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- bottom row -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <!-- bottom left zone -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- bottom right zone -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You would have to define two new zones. Copy and paste the top zone. Don't forget to change the Id and name properties of the zones.

Regards

Comment: You can use above in a page layout and than change the page layout of Default.aspx to your custom one. [Changing page layout](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/change-page-layout-via-sharepoint-2010s-publishing.html)

Comment: You can also create a new page (a Web Part page or a publishing page) and set it as your start page. [Change default start page](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html)

Comment: @Arsalan thank You very much for response! I'll try tomorrow and ping You back!